# How to get array object key as a comma separated string in flatlist react native

Tags: javascript

I have an array which again consist of array objects. Can anyone tell how to get object key values separated with commas

```
  sizeData: [
    headerId : 1,
    amount: 200,
    sizes: [
       {
         id: 1,
         cname: "120 xl",
         code: 2001,
       },
       {
         id: 2,
         cname: "10 m",
         code: 2071,
       }
    ]
  ]
```

How to get string as "120xl, 10m"

Comment: This syntax is invalid.  You're missing the `{}` around the top level object in the array

Comment: @Taplar is correct. also your use of the term 'key' is incorrect. you want the value of the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this has anything specific to do with RN / Flatlist - if it does please update your code with the component code.

Anyway, in plain JavaScript, once we correct the syntax error that @Taplar pointed out, we can do this:

```js
const sizeData = {
  headerId: 1,
  amount: 200,
  sizes: [{
      id: 1,
      cname: "120 xl",
      code: 2001,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      cname: "10 m",
      code: 2071,
    }
  ]
}

const cnames = sizeData.sizes.map(({
  cname
}) => cname).join(', ')

console.log(cnames)
```